# Trying to apply real time patch to kernel 4.9.76

Tags: pi-3, kernel, raspbian-stretch, real-time

- Raspberry Pi 3 model B
- OS: Raspbian 9.3 stretch
- Kernel: armv7l Linux 4.9.76-v7+
- CPU: ARMv7 rev 4 (v7l) @ 1.2GHz RAM: 1GB

---

I'm trying to apply the real-time patch (it's highly desirable for my project). I sourced the patch from [the following site](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.9/). After `wget`-ing `patch-4.9.76-rt61.patch` I then ran `cat patch-4.9.76-rt61.patch | patch -p1`. The issue is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rt $ cat patch-4.9.76-rt61.patch | patch -p1
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/Documentation/sysrq.txt b/Documentation/sysrq.txt
|index 3a3b30ac2a75..9e0745cafbd8 100644
|--- a/Documentation/sysrq.txt
|+++ b/Documentation/sysrq.txt
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

This is my first time patching so perhaps it's an obvious mistake but I don't understand the "File to patch:..." bit. Didn't I just pipe the contents into it?

Comment: did you download the kernel sources? are they in the same folder as the patch? did you take a look if Documentation/sysrq.txt is there?

Comment: Do you have to apply patches to kernel source code then compile? I thought it being a patch that it would just apply to the current working kernel hence the diff tags.

Comment: yes the patch patches the kernel source code, you can not patch a binary

Comment: did you take a look at these links: http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203 https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md ?

Comment: Yeah I actually installed that precompiled kernel onto my Pi earlier and it just failed to boot. I think it was due to the hardware difference being `BCM2708` and mine being `BCM 2709` but I'm not really sure myself. If I have to do the actual building that's fine but if there's an easier way to do it why make life harder I suppose.

Comment: Also on [this article](https://medium.com/@metebalci/latency-of-raspberry-pi-3-on-standard-and-real-time-linux-4-9-kernel-2d9c20704495) talking about the area. The poster mentions "Running the cyclic test program above causes instability after a few minutes. So I have applied this patch, and there was no problem." So is that another thing to consider? The author is on a more recent version than the guide you posted.

Comment: I ran cyclistest for several hours with stock kernel without issus.

Comment: With real-time kernel patch? I've done it with stock raspbian already but I need to get real-time kernel now.

Comment: In the article you linked the issues arise with cyclictest and the stock kernel, I tested both with and without patch for several hours with no issues. stock kernel gave 6000µs reaction times when switching on and off the usb controller. RT Kernel is always below 250µs

Comment: Thanks for your help so far by the way. So you suggest I follow the guide that you posted to get what I want. If so, looking through the guide I'm not sure how I would do the following "Next, patch the kernel with the RT Preempt patch. Choose the patch matching your kernel version. To this end, have a look at the Makefile. VERSION, PATCHLEVEL, and SUBLEVEL define the kernel version."

Comment: I'm not sure what to do at this point. I'm at the configuring the kernel part for Pi3. I have the following output.
`tom@mint ~ $ make bcmrpi_defconfig make: *** No rule to make target 'bcmrpi_defconfig'. Stop.`

Comment: Looking more at the export paths. The following command is incomplete at the end `export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/user/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-` there is a load of files it *could* be but I have no idea which one nor where to even begine with them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the sources, this worked for me (only valid for Cross compiling on 64-bit linux for Raspberry Pi 3):

```
cd ~
sudo rm -rf ~/linux #only if checked out before
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
cd linux
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.9/patch-4.9.76-rt61.patch.gz
zcat patch-4.9.76-rt61.patch.gz | patch -p1
export KERNEL=kernel7
make -j 4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bcm2709_defconfig
nano .config
#CTRL-W search for PREEMPT, comment out whatever sheduler is selected and comment in CONFIG_PREEMT_RT_FULL=y
make -j 6 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs
```

adjust for latest rt patch

```
echo $PATH
```

should give:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/half-borg/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin
```

at least for 64 bit hosts, which is every recent host

Resources:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203

Comment: added this because posting commands in comments is rather hard to read, I know this is not a high quality answer and will probably be outdated soon

Comment: Yeah commenting on here sucks. Thanks for the answer. Do you not need the tools though?
https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git

Comment: So I just comment out the one thing? There is still a lot of `PREEMPT` stuff in the `.config` file.

Comment: yes you need the tools, and you need to do the bashrc thing, but only once, if you do it more than once it will mess up your shell. I only changed two lines in the config. You can also try "make menuconfig" but that was breaking things for me

Comment: does making defconfig work for you now? thats very important

Comment: Yes. I'm currently editing `.config`. I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: Doing the final `make -j ...` I get options as it's working through it all. For example "Debug preemptible kernel [Y/n]"

Comment: yes, it might ask again for the sheduler, everything can go with default and will be working for now, turning debug off will improve performance, but I guess you're testing for now so it might come in handy

Comment: I'm afraid I get [the following output](https://pastebin.com/hzTyJTvH) when I leave all the defaults. Is it due to the absence of the correct tools?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71976/discussion-between-shmink-and-christian).